# Simple library management system using python

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

I am trying to implement a small library management systems using python. We are given a functionality list. The functionality I am stuck on is this part:

- Implement a Python function that adds a book to the library.
  Your function should ask for the book ISBN, title, author and how many copies have been purchased. The function should update the library inventory (the dictionary) to include the new book.
  If the book is already in the library the system should update the quantity.

my dictionary is as follows. Key = ISBN, Values = Copies/Title/Author

```
library = {4139770544441: [5,'Hello World','John'],
           4139770544442: [2,'Red Sky','Mary'],
           4139770544443: [8,'The Road','Chris']}
```

Below is the function i have to add a book:

```
def add_book(key, amount, library):
    for current_key in library.keys():
        if current_key == key:
            library[current_key] = library[current_key] + amount
            # amount updated
            # get out of the loop and the function
            return


    #item doesn't exist in the list, add it with the specified amount
    library[key] = amount

#User inputs new book titles
enter_copies = int(input('Please enter number of copies to add: '))
enter_title = input('Please enter the Title of the book: ')
enter_author = input('Please enter the Author of the book: ')



#relates to add_book Function
add_book(enter_book, [enter_copies, enter_title, enter_author], library)
```

If it is a new book i want it to add on to the dictionary and if it is an existing book i want it to increase the number of copies. However what is happening is that is just adds the isbn (key) and the values on at the end regardless if it exists or not. ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try writing the function like this:

```
def add_book(key, amount, library):
    current_key = library.keys()
    if key in current_key:
        library[key][0] += amount[0]
    else:
        library[key] = amount
    return library
```

Comment: and remember to save the returned value `library` to DB(whatever kind of database you are using with), else next time you get the `library dict`, it`s the same as before and nothing changed.